# i want to make circuit to drop voltage 24v input to 10v output by using resister

Tags: voltage-regulator

i want to make circuit to drop voltage 24v input to 10v output by using resister By the help of pot meter.

Comment: No useful (to you) answer can be given with so little information. What current, for what purpose, and what do you expect the potentiometer to do exactly?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I disagree that my answer is useless to the OP; I'm telling him he can't use just a resistor (regardless of current) and why, and here are a couple of alternatives.  I agree the part about the pot is bonkers.

Comment: @tcrosley the problem with low-quality questions is that answers have to make too many assumptions. If you take a step back couldn't the question really be about how to interface a 24V sensor to a 0-10V analog input in which case a pot / resistors may be appropriate? I see nothing to indicate any significant current draw is required.

Comment: @PeterJ I agree it is a poor question and I had to make some assumptions.  I've revised my answer to make that more clear.  I did assume the 10V is a power rail, since the voltage would be too high for any microcontroller ADC.  If I'm wrong I'll have to delete my answer.

Comment: @tcrosley No offense intended, and your answer is well crafted and makes some reasonable assumptions. My comment was  directed at the OP for making you (and us) guess, so she or he will learn that despite getting a long and well thought out answer they did not provide enough information for their particular situation. Otherwise, we'll be encouraging this sort of thing and they'll never learn.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks for the clarification.  I misread your first comment as implying my answer was useless, and I see you were saying something different.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you mean by "By the help of pot meter."  So I'm going to ignore that for now.

Your question also doesn't state the purpose of the 10 V, whether it is a poweer rail (which I am assuming), or simply an input to an analog circuit such as an op-amp or ADC input.

Using a resistor to drop a voltage for purposes of supplying power is a *very very* bad idea.  First of all, it only works if the current being drawn at the other end is known and constant.  If it is not constant, then the voltage drop will not be constant as the current varies.

The second problem is the heat generated in the resistor due to the voltage drop across it.  You didn't mention the current (again it must be constant) but lets assume it 500 mA.  The power across the resistor will be VxI or 14V x 0.5A = 7 W.  To be safe, you would need at least a 10 W resistor, and that would get plenty warm.  10 W is a hefty resistor.  Even if your current drain is only 100 mA, you are still talking about 1.4 W, requiring at least a 2 W resistor.

So forget about using a resistor.

The next simplest solution is to use a linear regulator, such as the [LM317](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM317T.pdf).  This at least allows for a varying current drain.  But you still have a problem with heat, as you need to dissipate the same power inside the chip. According to a [TI engineer](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power_management/linear_regulators/f/321/t/211429),  the LM317 can handle up to 20 W with a proper hatsink.  So you should be able to handle up to 750 mA or so, provided you also have a hefty heatsink.

The best solution is to use a [buck regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter).  It will drop the voltage without encountering the heat issue.

The [L4971](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00001355.pdf) takes an input voltage from 8V to 55V, and outputs an adjustable voltage anywhere from 3.3V to 50V.  It comes in a hobbyist friendly 8-pin DIP package.